# How can I customize the Content Field with CSS?

Tags: cognito-forms

I don't find the specific class CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with Cognito Forms.

You can use CSS to target and change the text of the Content Field if you are embedding your from on your website. You will be able to target the different tags inside of the Content Field for more control eg; P, H1, H2..

```
.cognito .c-html p {color:#FF0000;}
```